# What does “so” mean in “So macht Lernen Spaß!”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *so* mean in this title?

> So macht Lernen Spaß! – Film *Tanzen wie die Stars*

The film is about a *Tanzschule.* I have a few ideas what it could mean, but *so* got [so many meanings](http://en.pons.com/translate?l=dedx&q=so) that I’m not sure.

Comment: Welche Ideen hast Du?

Comment: So macht Lernen Spaß! literally: Making learning fun. It means: This is the way how learning is fun.

Answer (score 8):

In this context, "so" can be translated as "in this way..." or "that's how..."

Answer (score 4):

That is actually the essence of the word "so".
To every question, there is one super generic answer. This generic answer means nothing by itself because it is just a reference, either to something that is verbalized or to something that is actually being pointed at.

> Wann   - dann
>   Wo     - da
>   Was    - das
>   ...

"So" is the generic answer to "wie".

> Wie? So.
>   How? Like that.

In this case it seems to be a headline, so "so" is basically referring to whatever comes after... probably a description of sorts.

For a more detailed take on "so", check out [**this article**](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/meaning-german-so/) on my blog.

Comment: So macht man Antworten viiieeel zu lang...